# VBA convert Excel - HTML for Outlook but lost border formatting when sent - still remain in draft

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

RangetoHTML has worked greatly https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm.

Up to today, I want to highlight some cells' border to separate different date series in a column.

[image: the thick green line] (the thick green (xlThick) border to separate 11/09/2023 and 14/08/2023)

RangetoHTML still can help me to keep the line in Outlook draft but completely **lost in mail sent/received**:
[image]
[image]

Please help me with this. I am using Office 365.

Thank you.